# Formatar CEP na Consulta - Mysql

Tags: mysql

Na minha coluna do banco tenho o campo CEP varchar(20), e um registro: "92820142" existe alguma forma de formatar no padrão: 92.820-142 durante a consulta?

Tentei utilizar o format, mas conflitou no tipo de dados.

Comment: Normalmente isso é tratado na camada de apresentação. Tem certeza que quer tratar a nível de consulta?

Comment: Sim Jefferson, é proposital, um trabalho de faculdade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utilize esta função:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION mask (unformatted_value BIGINT, format_string CHAR(32))
RETURNS CHAR(32) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
# Declare variables
DECLARE input_len TINYINT;
DECLARE output_len TINYINT;
DECLARE temp_char CHAR;

# Initialize variables
SET input_len = LENGTH(unformatted_value);
SET output_len = LENGTH(format_string);

# Construct formated string
WHILE ( output_len > 0 ) DO

SET temp_char = SUBSTR(format_string, output_len, 1);
IF ( temp_char = '#' ) THEN
IF ( input_len > 0 ) THEN
SET format_string = INSERT(format_string, output_len, 1, SUBSTR(unformatted_value, input_len, 1));
SET input_len = input_len - 1;
ELSE
SET format_string = INSERT(format_string, output_len, 1, '0');
END IF;
END IF;

SET output_len = output_len - 1;
END WHILE;

RETURN format_string;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Como utilizar:

```
mysql> select mask(123456789,'###-##-####');
+-------------------------------+
| mask(123456789,'###-##-####') |
+-------------------------------+
| 123-45-6789                   |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select mask(123456789,'(###) ###-####');
+----------------------------------+
| mask(123456789,'(###) ###-####') |
+----------------------------------+
| (012) 345-6789                   |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select mask(123456789,'###-#!##@(###)');
+----------------------------------+
| mask(123456789,'###-#!##@(###)') |
+----------------------------------+
| 123-4!56@(789)                   |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112718/mysql-output-masking-i-e-phone-number-ssn-etc-display-formatting

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples acredito que é utilizando CONCAT() junto com SUBSTRING:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CEP,1,2),'.',SUBSTRING(CEP,3,3),'-',SUBSTRING(CEP,6,3)) FROM {suatabela} WHERE ...
```

Vai funcionar se todos estiverem no padrão de 8 dígitos sem nenhum outro caracter, como "." ou "-".